# Use OAuth 2.0 in Firefox WebExtension

Tags: javascript, firefox, oauth

I have built an open sourced extension some time ago, and the extension needs OAuth 2.0 to access some Google Drive API.

Currently, my [Chrome extension](https://github.com/walty8/simple-gmail-notes.chrome) uses [identity.launchWebAuthFlow](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity#method-launchWebAuthFlow) to access to the OAuth, and Firefox XPI extension uses [oauthorizer](https://github.com/mozilla/oauthorizer) for the OAuth.

Now, I want to convert the Firefox extension from XPI to [WebExtension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions) for easier maintenance in the future (as Chrome and Firefox WebExtensions are very much alike).

I thought the migration should be easy as I already got two versions of extensions on hand. But after some research I can't find an easy way to access the OAuth 2.0 inside the Firefox WebExtension.

Some advices would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I have later posted the same question in the [mozilla forum](https://discourse.mozilla-community.org/t/use-oauth-2-0-in-firefox-webextension/11984/2), and it seems the corresponding API is still under implementation for now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently using it!

Bug here:
https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1305421

you can see if features are supported here:

http://arewewebextensionsyet.com/#identity

Comment: hi, I wonder if the API is already released? I saw it's supported in your provided URL, but I got error of `Unchecked lastError value: Error: browser.identity is undefined` when trying to use it (in FF51 & FF52 developer edition). And I could not find the official documentation in the FF website.